# evaluate angular curly brackets(i.e. compile html template) in custom directive

Tags: angularjs-directive

I want to display header and footer HTML template in angular custom directive. HTML template would be supplied from config which also contains angular curly brackets. i.e. '{{name}}'. Somehow I am not able to evaluate name which is specified inside curly brackets. I have written a [plunker for demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/I8ARww?p=info).

In this plunk, headerInfo contains HTML string which would be passed from config along with scope variable in curly brackets. This scope variable is available in directive controller.

Overall idea of this directive is to plot chart using NVD3 library. Chart is working fine. Now I want to add header/footer div in this directive which should take HTML template. This HTML tag would be like -
`<div align='center'>{{header}}</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to compile HTML template in directive using custom directive NgHtmlCompile. I have updated my plunk -    `https://plnkr.co/edit/I8ARww?p=preview`

reference     `https://github.com/francisbouvier/ng_html_compile`